# How can I get polygons for every country in the world using mapping toolbox?

Tags: matlab

I'm hoping I can get something like a cell array of polygons for all the land area of the world, by country (or other label, such as "antarctica").  I have the mapping toolbox, but I'm not really interesting in using the custom plots.  This information would be useful for things like telling which country a point is in and such.

Comment: Did you read the documentation page "[Map / Create and Display Polygons](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/create-and-display-polygons.html)"?

Comment: The question is about how to get the raw data from the mapping toolbox in the first place, or if it exists in the toolbox at all.  I would assume such basic info would be included, but I don't know how to tell.